# How to restrict accounts in token based authentication

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth, openid

I'm tasked with authenticating an access token being passed by a react client in my .net core API. The access token in question is issued by google. Now I'm trying to figure out how to structure my API such that the endpoints are restricted to a predetermined set of google accounts. What is the best way and best practice to go about enforcing the restriction? Should I store a set of google IDs in my database and check the google Ids against the payload of the token being passed by the client? I'm relatively new to the whole concept of OpenID and OAuth and authentication so I'm not sure if the process I described follows specifications. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the following?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I ended up using Auth0's services for my needs and everything worked out. Thanks for sharing the links though they're very insightful :)